# Are in-app-purchases applied after an app reinstall?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

If I purchase an in-app-purchase (e.g., in-game currency or content) and I will remove the app and install it later, will the in-app-purchase content still be accessible?

For example:

- Plants VS Zombie 2 Coins
- Where's my Water additional content

Comment: As long as you use the same Google Account, you should be able to restore all In-App Purchases. Else the app is poorly written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes. The content you purchased via an in-app-purchase will persist between installs (and even across devices). The purchase is tied to the account and will usually be restored upon installing the app again.

There may be rare cases, where the developer has not done this; but for the most part they do.