# Will I get back my IAPs after reinstaling a purchased app from the Google Play?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, in-app-purchase

So I was wondering if I will get back my IAPs after reinstalling an app from the Google Play Store. It's because I have an app where I've made a lot of IAPs and I've uninstalled it due to insufficient storage.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also duplicate of  [Are in-app-purchases applied after an app reinstall?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/104865/131553)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your in-app purchases are saved on your Google account. When you re-install an app it should restore the purchases given that you are logged in with the account you used to purchase.

Sometimes the app doesn't restore the purchases. In this case you should find a button in an app saying something like `Restore In-App Purchases` and click it. You should have everything you purchased.

If you still don't have your purchases restored you should contact the developer. Since your purchases are stored on your Google account they can verify that you paid and restore your purchases manually.