# In-app purchase on google play

Tags: reboot, google-apps, delete, in-app-purchase

Lets say i have an app I've recently downloaded and have made an in-app purchase on this app, if i were to uninstall this app and reinstall later on will my in-app purchase still be available? ( also same situation if i where to reboot my device)

Comment: Many apps offer the functionality of "restore in-app purchase". Look for it, make sure it's there before you purchase anything.

Comment: Duplicate of this also https://android.stackexchange.com/q/104865/131553

Answer (score 0):

First, a reboot will never "revert" your completed IAP, and never should it (unless serious problems with hardware that causes data loss).

When you uninstall and re-install an app (or simply clears its data), then:

- If that app supports cloud backup, your data will be recovered and nothing is lost or reverted
- If that app has no backup then:

  - **All consumable purchases are lost, so is your dollars.**
  - **All non-consumable purchases are also lost, but [they are supposed to be restorable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16933788/5958455)** (not "recoverable")

See [Consumable and non-consumable purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32883370/5958455).

- **Consumable** purchases are like golds, gems and timed boosts that does not last forever.
- **Non-consumable** purchases are like premium unlocks, special characters and coin doublers that lasts forever after purchase.